# iOS Unable to Disable Horizontal Scrolling when swipe the screen in scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I have to implement ScrollView and page control, I used ScrollView for both vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling. when I drag the screen with scroll horizontal means it works fine but when I drag the screen with scroll Vertical means it has some glitches like(scrolling both vertically and horizontally) unable to stop that or unable to find the issue.

So I decided to place two buttons named next and previous for horizontal scrolling for next page and previous page in page control so I want to stop horizontal scroll when dragging the screen, but I don't know how to stop horizontal scrolling(not vertical scrolling).

Here I have posted the code for Scrolling in page control and Next and previous button actions.

I have declared and called the ScrollView Delegate.

```
UIScrollViewDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePageControl()

    scrollMainHolderView.delegate = self
    scrollMainHolderView.isPagingEnabled = true

}
```

ScrollView Method is:

```
//MARK:- Scrollview delegate -
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControlNew.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    self.scrollMainHolderView.contentSize=CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(templateMutArray.count), height: CGFloat((globalYarr[Int(pageNumber)] as? CGFloat)!))
}
```

Set up code for Page control,

```
func configurePageControl() {
    self.pageControlNew.numberOfPages = templateMutArray.count
    self.pageControlNew.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControlNew.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.pageControlNew.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControlNew.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Code for next and previous button action is,

```
@IBAction func pagePreviousBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    isHorizontalSCrolling = true
    scrollMainHolderView.delegate = self
    let scrollBounds = self.scrollMainHolderView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.scrollMainHolderView.contentOffset.x - scrollBounds.size.width))
    self.movScrollToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

}
@IBAction func pageNextBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    isHorizontalSCrolling = true
    scrollMainHolderView.delegate = self
    let scrollBounds = self.scrollMainHolderView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.scrollMainHolderView.contentOffset.x + scrollBounds.size.width))
    self.movScrollToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

}
```

Comment: what is the reason for using both scroll view and page control?

Comment: Page control for navigate between pages and scrollview for scrolling vertical because the content was more the screen display.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from the comments is that you want to stop horizontal scrolling. That is actually pretty straight forward.

You can stop horizontal scrolling or vertical scrolling in the `ScrollViewDelegate` Method. Here it is how,

Setting the `contentOffset.x` value to `zero` will prevent the scrollview scroll in horizontal direction.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    sender.contentOffset.x = 0.0
}
```